# MS Access VBA on Dateadd's for current day

Tags: vba, ms-access

I've got a question on the dateadd statement I'm using. The idea is that a form pops up with the day of the week and you can select it to add a due date. 
IE: You select Monday and if it is Monday then it will give you a due day of Monday but if it's Tuesday then the following Monday will be used for your due date.

The issue is that if it's Monday and you select Monday it is giving you the following Monday as a due date and not that current day.

Here is the statement I'm using...

```
 DateAdd('d',8-Weekday(Date(),4),Date())
```

I'm not sure how to make this correction since this seems correct to me. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should also work:

`DateAdd('d',(8-Weekday(Date(),4)) mod 7,Date())`

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work.

```
thisday = date()

dateadd("d",7-weekday(thisday, vbTuesday), thisday)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to use a 1 line solution, then a small function would be quite handy. It checks the current day with `Weekday()` and if it is `vbMonday` it returns it. If not, it gives the next Monday.

```
Public Function NextMonday(selectedDate As Date) As Date

    Dim returnMonday As Date

    If Weekday(selectedDate) = vbMonday Then
        NextMonday = selectedDate
    Else
        NextMonday = selectedDate + 8 - Weekday(selectedDate, vbMonday)
    End If

End Function
```

And it works:

```
Sub TestMe()

    'Monday:
    Debug.Print NextMonday(DateSerial(2019, 6, 10))
    Debug.Print NextMonday(DateSerial(2019, 6, 17))

    'Not Monday:
    Debug.Print NextMonday(DateSerial(2019, 6, 7))
    Debug.Print NextMonday(DateSerial(2019, 6, 11))

End Sub
```